# VS can't find the namespace in 15.9.13 (but can find in 15.9.11)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I have a class with a namespace of:

```
CompanyName.DataSource.Query.Entity

public class Command {}
```

The unit test using a namespace of:

```
CompanyName.DataSource.UnitTests
```

So inside the unit tests, we have this:

```
var cmd = new Query.Entity.Command()
```

That code compiles fine in VS2017 v15.9.11, but will fail in v15.9.13. I have to use one step outside to be:

```
var cmd = new DataSource.Query.Entity.Command()
```

Is this on VS or is there anything I could do on my side?

Comment: Will fail - does it just say "failed" or does it *give you an error message*?

Comment: The typical error: The type or namespace name 'Command' does not exist in the namespace 'CompanyName.DataSource.UnitTests.Query' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Comment: Right, so it's telling you you now have a `Query` type or namespace *inside* your unit tests, and that's the one that's winning when you just say `Query` at the start of a name.

Comment: I would say that in the new version it is correctly parsed. `Command` is in fact not in `CompanyName.DataSource.UnitTests`. If you haven't declared any other usings how would it find `Query.Entity.Command`?

Comment: Ahh if you think of it that way, in fact the new version is correct. It's just that I've been too used with the old way that I never thought of it as wrong...